# APEX refresh- issue with the page refreshing even before db changes

Tags: oracle-apex, refresh, page-refresh

I created a classic report in apex. It is essentially a simple notification system.
The aim of this report is to see active notifications. But I also want the user to be able to close each notification. For this purpose I created a virtual column called 'Close' and made it a link. Each row has an icon of a trash can. When the user presses it, it will update a column in the database from IS_READ= 0 to IS_READ=1.
The system works great, however I am having trouble with proper refresh.
When I delete a notification, the page refrershes, but it displays the old state, the notification is still there. However, when I refresh the page manually, the notification will disappear.
I tried all sorts of refreshing techniques (dynamic actions) and triggers but nothing works correctly.
Can you please advise me on how to do a refresh only after the change has happened in the database?
Here is an explanation how my page is configured:
This is the notification system
[image]

And this is my Dynamic action to delete (update) the records. The .delete-irrow is a jQuery selector of the trash can icon
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dynamic action to `execute javascript code`.
Then in your javascript code, use a success callback as follows:

```
apex.server.process("PP_UPDATETABLE", {}, {
  success: function(pData) {
    if (pData.success) {
          apex.region('yourregionsstaticid').refresh();
}
  }
})
```

Afterwards, the only thing you would need is to create an AJAX Callback process with the name: PP_UPDATETABLE on your page's processing section with the PL/SQL source of:

```
begin
    update yourtable
    set column = newvalue
    where id = :YOURIDFROMGRID;

    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('success',true);
    apex_json.close_object;
exception when others then
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('success',false);
    apex_json.close_object;
end;
```

This Ajax Callback makes sure that the region refresh code is only executed after the AJAX procedure you defined is returned successfully.
If you want further help or details, I suggest you to create a APEX sample application with the same grid/table etc. and share the link and credentials.